# R Function 'box::help()' Cannot Generate Help File: "Invalid Argument"

Tags: r, module, filepath, roxygen2, r-box

## Motivation

My colleagues and I routinely create ad hoc scripts in R, to perform ETL on proprietary data and generate automated reports for clients. I am attempting to standardize our approach, for the sake of consistency, modularity, and reusability.

In particular, I want to consolidate our most commonly used functions in a central directory, and to access them as if they were functions from a proprietary R package. However, I am quite raw as an R developer, and my teammates are even less experienced in R development. As such, the development of a *formal package* is unfeasible for the moment.

## Approach

Fortunately, the [`box`](https://github.com/klmr/box) package, by Stack Overflow's very own [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968), provides (among other modularity) an accessible approach to approximate the behavior of an R package.  Unlike the rigorous [development process](https://r-pkgs.org) outlined by the RStudio team, `box` [requires](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/box/vignettes/box.html) only that one create a regular `.R` file, in a meaningful location, with [`roxygen2`](https://r-pkgs.org/man.html#man-workflow) documentation (`#'`) and explicit [`@export`](https://r-pkgs.org/namespace.html#exports)s:

> ### Writing modules
>
> The module `bio/seq`, which we have used in the previous section, is
> implemented in the file `bio/seq.r`. The file `seq.r` is,
> by and large, a normal R source file, which happens to live in a
> directory named `bio`.
>
> In fact, there are only three things worth mentioning:
>
> 1. Documentation. Functions in the module file can be documented using    ‘[roxygen2](https://cran.r-project.org/package=roxygen2)’    syntax.
>    It works the same as for packages. The ‘box’ package parses the
>    documentation and makes it available via `box::help`. *Displaying
>    module help    requires that ‘roxygen2’ is installed.*
> 2. Export declarations. Similar to packages, modules explicitly need to declare    which names they export; they do this using the
>    annotation comment `#'    @export` in front of the name. Again, this
>    works similarly to ‘roxygen2’ (but    does *not* require having that
>    package installed).
>
> ⋮

At the moment, I am tinkering around with a particular module, as "imported" into a script. While the "import" itself works seamlessly, I cannot seem to access the documentation for my functions.

## Code

I am experimenting with `box` on a Lenovo ThinkPad running Windows 10 Enterprise. I have created a script, aptly titled `Script.R`, whose location serves as my working directory. My module exists in the relative subdirectory `./Resources/Modules` as the humble file `time.R`, reproduced here:

```
###########################
## Relative Date Windows ##
###########################

#' @title Past Day of Week
#' @description Determine the date of the given weekday that fell a given number
#'   of weeks before the given date.
#' @param from \code{Date} object. The point of reference, from which we go
#'   backwards. Defaults to current \code{Sys.Date()}.
#' @param back \code{integer}. The number of weeks to go backward from the point
#'   of reference; negative values go forward. Defaults to \code{1}, for last
#'   week. Weeks begin on \code{"Monday"}.
#' @param weekday \code{character}. The weekday within the week targeted by
#'   \code{back}; one of \code{c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
#'   "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")}.
#' @export
#' @return The date of the \code{weekday} falling in the week \code{back} weeks
#'   prior to the week in which \code{from} falls. Defaults to \code{"Monday"}.
past_weekday <- function(from = Sys.Date(),
                         back = 1,
                         weekday = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
                         ) {
  cycle <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
  
  from <- as.Date(from)
  back <- as.integer(back)
  
  weekday_index <- (which(cycle == weekday[1]) - 1) %% 7
  
  from_index <- (which(cycle == "Sunday") + as.POSIXlt(from)$wday - 1) %% 7
  
  weekdate <- as.Date(from) - lubridate::days(from_index) - lubridate::weeks(as.numeric(back)) + lubridate::days(weekday_index)
  
  return(as.Date(weekdate))
}
```

Observe the `roxygen2` documentation, as indicated by the special `#'` comments and `@` tags. The *documentation* for `past_weekday()` is of far greater interest to me than the function *itself*.

Last and certainly least, here is reproduced `Script.R` itself:

```
# Set the working directory to the location of this very script.
setwd(this.path::this.dir())

# Access the functions in 'time.R' by relative location.
box::use(Resources/Modules/time)

# Run the function with its default values.
time$past_weekday()

# View the help page for the function.
box::help(time$past_weekday)
```

In theory, that final line will display the documentation for `past_weekday()`, via [`box::help()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/box/box.pdf):

[image]

The `box` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/box/vignettes/box.html#using-modules) gives a simple example to that effect:

> We can also display the interactive help for individual names using the `box::help` function, e.g.:
>
> ```
>  box::help(seq$revcomp)
> ```

## Problem

The first three lines of `Script.R` give me exactly what I desire.  That is, they load `time` into R as an environment, from which I can access `past_weekday()` via `time$past_weekday()`. This `module$function()` syntax is analogous to the qualification of functions from formal packages: `package::function()`.  Indeed, `past_weekday()` itself works just as expected:

```
time$past_weekday()
# [1] "2021-07-19"
```

However, when I attempt to interactively access the documentation

```
box::help(time$past_weekday)
```

the console displays the following warnings

```
Warning messages:
1: In utils::packageDescription(package, fields = "Version") :
  no package 'PKG' was found
2: In file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file 'C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYBTTyG/.R/doc/html/module:Resources/Modules/time.html', reason 'Invalid argument'
```

and the interactive help window is empty but for this error message:

[image]

**For my team, this could prove a serious issue.**  Since we often rely on useful functions written by each other, it is crucial that any user on our team be able to easily access clear documentation by the author of the function...just as the user is accustomed to doing with formal R packages.  Without this ability, the user must either bug the author for clarification, or blunder ahead without a clear understanding of the function's purpose and limitations.

## Suspicions

When I read the warning

```
In file.create(to[okay]) :
cannot create file 'C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYBTTyG/.R/doc/html/module:Resources/Modules/time.html', reason 'Invalid argument'
```

I was drawn to the filepath

```
C:\Users\greg\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYBTTyG/.R/doc/html/module:Resources/Modules/time.html
```

as the cause for an `Invalid argument` to `file.create()`. **To my knowledge, a directory name `.../module:Resources/...` containing a colon `:` is illegal on Windows** [<s>and elsewhere</s>](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121207252).

Indeed, when I supply another illegal filepath `./illegal:directory:name/missing.txt` to `file.create()`

```
file.create('./illegal:directory:name/missing.txt')
# [1] FALSE
```

I get the same warning:

```
Warning message:
In file.create("./illegal:directory:name/missing.txt") :
  cannot create file './illegal:directory:name/missing.txt', reason 'Invalid argument'
```

The culprit appears to be [this line](https://github.com/klmr/box/blob/f1455c3ba751616f86272314fcf426c871c1b535/R/help.r#L86) in [`help.R`](https://github.com/klmr/box/blob/main/R/help.r):

```
display_help(doc, paste0('module:', mod_name), help_type)
#                               ^
#                             Here
```

**However**, this seems far **too simple** a diagnosis. Frankly, I would be quite surprised to find such a portability issue within a package designed by a seasoned developer. I find it overwhelmingly more likely that I am simply out of my depth.

### What am I missing?

---

## Update 1

I tried it on my MacBook Air, running Mojave, and it actually worked!  While I still got the first (rather odd) warning message on the console

```
Warning message:
In utils::packageDescription(package, fields = "Version") :
  no package 'PKG' was found
```

the interactive help window **does display** the intended documentation:

[image]

Naturally, this does not exactly solve my problem—the scripts will be executed on a VM running Windows, just like my Lenovo and every other computer used at my company.  However, **it does support the hypothesis that this issue is specific to `box` *on Windows***.

---

## Update 2

Konrad has kindly [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/121224899) that this is indeed a **bug**, and he's [working on a fix](https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/223#issuecomment-890023798).  **Many thanks to Konrad for his clarification and responsiveness!**

Comment: Colons are perfectly legal on Unix filesystems.  Windows is unique in not allowing them.  But that doesn't really matter:  R packages are easy to write.  Use one of those (supported by thousands of experienced R users) if this package doesn't work for you.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks for the advice! Unfortunately, we are restricted exclusively to Windows, as the automations are triggered on a Windows VM. More importantly, when you say *"R packages are easy to write"*, I should note I am too inexperienced to write a formal package efficiently, and (to my knowledge) my teammates have no experience whatsoever in developing packages. And we do indeed need to create a custom "package", containing our own helper functions that we use on a routine basis. As it stands, I am unfamiliar with any alternatives to `box`, for making "informal packages".  Know of any?

Comment: No, I know of no alternatives to `box`, nor any need for one.  As I said, packages are easy to write.  Personally I'd start with the old fashioned `package.skeleton()` function, but it's probably even easier to use the more recent `usethis::create_package()` function.  Try it!

Comment: Put simply, that’s a bug. Thanks for reporting it, I’ll be working on a fix shortly!

Comment: Thank you @KonradRudolph, I really appreciate it!  I wanted to disambiguate things by creating an `r-box` tag, but I lack the requisite rep/privileges, so thanks for that too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, [that’s a bug](https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/223), now [fixed](https://github.com/klmr/box/pull/224).

But since we’re here, a word on usage:

> ```
> # Set the working directory to the location of this very script.
> setwd(this.path::this.dir())
> ```

This is generally not recommended. To quote [Jenny Bryan](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/):

> If the first line of your R script is
>
> ```
> setwd("C:\Users\jenny\path\that\only\I\have")
> ```
>
> I will come into your office and SET YOUR COMPUTER ON FIRE .

‘box’ also doesn’t need this; instead, the idea is to configure a [global module search path](https://klmr.me/box/reference/use.html#search-path) (equivalent to R’s package library, see `.libPaths()`), e.g. via the `box.path` option (this would usually go into the user’s `.Rprofile` configuration — *not* in the script itself!):

```
options(box.path = 'C:\User\Konrad\some\path')
```

Afterwards, modules that are installed in this search path will be found by `box::use`.

As noted, this should be a *global* setting. To use project-specific modules, you wouldn’t set a global search path; instead, you’d use relative imports:

```
box::use(./Resources/Modules/time)
```

This should work regardless of the working directory; it uses the calling script’s location instead. Consequently, `this.path::this.dir()` or similar hacks are never necessary with ‘box’. And to find data files, ‘box’ provides the [`box::file`](https://klmr.me/box/reference/file.html) function which also works regardless of the current working directory.

See also [FAQ: how to organise globally installed modules?](https://klmr.me/box/articles/faq.html#how-to-organise-globally-installed-modules-)

Comment: Hi Konrad, and thanks for taking the time to cover this in a formal answer!  To address your points: **(1)** Unlike the hardcoded path `"C:\Users\jenny\path\that\only\I\have"`, the call [`this.path::this.dir()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/this.path/versions/0.4.4/topics/this.path) is fully self-contained and portable for interactive use in RStudio, for `source()`ing, and for executables; indeed, my R projects using this approach have run swimmingly in other environments.  While I've always striven to implement these principles, it's good to see them codified by Jenny Bryan!

Comment: **(2)** I hope to make both of the following accessible from a script via `box`: **(a)** a global module of universally useful functions; and **(b)** local modules specific to each project. When digging into `box` yesterday, I was quite pleased to read of the `box.path` option, as it would easily allow my team to orient our separate scripts toward a central location. As for the relative imports, however, I should note that I previously tried `box::use(./Resources/Modules/time)`, *without* using `setwd(this.path::this.dir())`, but it **failed** for me within RStudio. Below is the error message:

Comment: `Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  Unable to load module “./Resources/Modules/time”; not found in “C:/Users/greg/OneDrive - My Company/Documents”
(inside “find_in_path(spec, mod_search_path(caller))”)`

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the error message. To clarify, is the code `box::use(./Resources/Modules/time)` inside an R source file which is open in RStudio, and which you’ve executed by sourcing the file or by pressing Ctrl+Return? And is that file stored in the `Documents` folder? Because if so, that should work.  I’ll investigate.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! To answer your questions: the code is indeed inside an R source file `Script.R`; this file is open in RStudio; and I have executed it via `source()` (and Ctrl+Return too). However, that file is **not** stored in the `Documents` folder. Rather, it is stored in the `Template (01)` directory nested under my `Desktop`; `Template (01)` also contains the subdirectory `Resources`, which contains the subdirectory `Modules`, which contains `time.R`. The full location of the folder is: `C:Users\greg\OneDrive - My Company\Desktop\Projects\Automations\Templates\Template (01)`

Comment: @Greg Thanks. Would you mind checking out the new [bug report](https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/225) I created for that?